# Can i use a single user to connect different databases in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I hava tried to create a user in database "admin" with roles of "root","readWriteManyDatabase" in mongodb to connect to different databases, but it seems that i can not use
this user to directly connect to the other databases, but i can do operations on other databases after run `db.auth()` in database admin.
So, is there any way i can use to connect directly to different databases with a same user but do not need to first connect to database "admin"

Comment: How are you connection to these databases?

Comment: I created a user in databases "admin" and use it like ```mongo localhost:27017/blogServer -u "username"  -p  "password"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're authentication with the admin database when connecting to the database server, this can be specified on the MongoDB Connection string by passing a query string parameter of `authSource`. For example:

```
mongodb://username:password@my-server/my-db?&authSource=admin
```

If you don't specify an auth source then it will try to authenticate using the database specified, in this case `my-db`

If you're using the shell you can specify this as an arugment of `authenticationDatabase` for example:

```
mongo localhost -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: Great, it solves my problems, but whether it means that if i want to use the user in admin to connect to other databases, i should authenticate it with admin database specifically after it?

Comment: Hi, there is another problem, I create the user in admin database, and when i try to  use this user to connect to another database named ```blogServer``` like:  
            ```mongodb://username:password@my-server/blogServer?&authSource=admin```, it failed with the info: ```database connection failed { MongoError: Authentication failed``` But when i exchange the ```blogServer``` and ```admin``` it works. Why?

Comment: That looks like a driver issue, maybe they've not fully implemented the authSource?

Comment: Yes, it is the problem in mongoose V5.2.0 and this problem has been fixed in latest version V5.2.1